# Translate one concave polygon to fit into another

Tags: computational-geometry

I need a fast and robust way to fit one concave polygon into another.

Polygons are presented as lists of points. 
Niether rotations nor scaling are allowed. Only translation. Also I'm not seeking for algorithm to find optimal emplacement.

Under the word "fast" I suppose computational complexity. I guess, assuming adjusted polygon has N vertices and destination one contains M vertices, algorithm that works for O(M*N) would be a nice one.

Or is it unreachable?

Any ideas or proofs of higher complexity are appreciated.

Comment: For each corner of the first polygon you want to find a set of vectors, such that if you shift the corner by these vectors, it will lie in the second polygon. This set is the second polygon, but shifted. Now you just intersect all these sets for all corners. Any vector in the intersection is feasible

Comment: What do you call optimal ? Don't you mean feasible ?

Comment: No. Here under the word "optimality" I mean some intuitive kind of reducing loss of material when cutting adjusted polygon from the destination one. See [Cutting_stock_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) for more info.

Comment: @Smooth: if there is a single polygon, I don't see what optimization you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally [dyukha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956272/dyukha)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363124/translate-one-concave-polygon-to-fit-into-another?noredirect=1#comment99329988_56363124) was very useful.

1. For each vertex in adjusted polygon you have to find sets of vectors that make this vertex fit into destination polygon. Actually, this set of vectors can be represented on surface as: *destination polygon shifted by -coordinates of this vertex*
2. All you have to do next is to find intersection of all this polygons. I used [Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) library for this purposes. Then, choose any point from the intersection set and translate the adjusted polygon by its coordinates.

Complexity of this algorithm would be about: O(N*M*log(M)) (Assuming we do not care about number of intersections between translation set polygons)

**Advancement:** What more, you can use the same algorithm for fitting polygon into another polygon *optimally* (in terms of [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)). Just iterate through interesting rotation angles (for my case I used just all possible angles between edges of polygons), apply the algorithm described above to all rotated figures and select from all possible translations one that moves adjusted polygon's gravity center to the farest position from destination polygon's gravity center.

Hope that could help anybody!

**Edit:** Forgot to mention. Fitting vertices is not a guarantee that edges do not cross. So on the second step you should choose the translation vector that does not result into intersecting adjusted polygon's edges with edges of the destination contour.

In my solution I used comparing square of intersection of both polygons with square of the destination contour. If they are equal, then don't care. Else choose another point.

Of course, this checks spoil performance a little bit, but it not so meaningful while finding best position of the polygon. As far as my experience says :).

Thanks [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust) for amendment.

Comment: I don't think that the solution by dyukha is correct. Because it only ensures that the vertices will fit, but not the edges. To deal with the edges, you can construct the erosions of the polygon, taking the edges as structuring elements.

Comment: Absolutely rigth! Edited the answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Oh, my bad, I thought that it were convex polygons, not concave.